# make image overflow from hidden to visible while hovering the image

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I have this situation:

```css
p {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 20px;
}
.Symbol {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.Symbol:hover {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="Symbol" style="height: 80px; position:relative">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/80x200" height="200" width="80"/>
</div>

<p>
text
</p>
```

When I hover the image then all of the image appears but when cursor comes over the p element then image overflow:visible disabled. I don't want that. I need the image to be on top of the other elements while hovering.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.Symbol:hover {
    overflow: visible;
    z-index:1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the z-index property in hover state to make the image lie above the text.

```
p {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 20px;
}
.Symbol {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.Symbol:hover {
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 10;
}

<div class="Symbol" style="height: 80px; position:relative">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/80x200" height="200" width="80"/>
</div>

<p>
text
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```css
p {
    position: absolute; /* position in div.Symbol */
    top: 50%; /* centering */
    margin-top: -10px; /* centering */
    left: 0;
    height: 20px;
}
.Symbol {
    position: relative; /* we try to position p */
    height: 80px;
}

.Symbol img {
    display: block; 
    max-height: 100%;
    opacity: 0; /* non visible */
    transition: opacity .2s; /* basic animation */
} 
.Symbol:hover img {
    opacity: 1; /* visible on :hover */
}
```

```html
<div class="Symbol">
    <img src="https://codingzap.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/html.png" alt=""/>
    <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the height of the element, if you don't do that, the element will have the same height, and the text will not be moved.

```css
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 20px;
}
.Symbol {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 80px;
}
.Symbol:hover {
    overflow: visible;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Symbol" style="position:relative">
    <img src="https//#" height="200" width="80"/>
</div>

<p>
text
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you but i don't want the text to be moved.